# ReduceByKey in spark scal in rdd not working

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to sum up all marks based on studentId. I have used reduceByKey. But it is throwing an error.
Can someone help me how to fix this issue.

```
scala> studentPairRDD.foreach(println)

Id,subject,marks,class

(3,social,40,10)

(4,maths,45,10)

(4,science,30,9)

(1,maths,90,8)

(1,science,90,9)

(1,social,80,10)

(2,maths,100,8)

(2,science,100,9)

(2,social,90,10)

(3,maths,35,9)

(3,science,36,8)

(4,social,42,8)

(5,maths,20,8)

(5,social,40,9)

(5,science,35,10)
```

based on the above result I have applied reducebyKey to sum marks of studentId.
But it is error

```
val totalmarksRDD = studentPairRDD.reduceByKey(_+_)

<console>:31: error: value reduceByKey is not a member of 

org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String, String, Double)]

val totalmarksRDD = studentPairRDD.reduceByKey(_+_)
```

Can someone help me how to fix this?

Comment: your RDD must be of `Tuple2` (key-value), in your case map it to `RDD[(String, (String, String, Double))] `

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is what I have written  val studentRDD = sc.textFile("file:///home/cloudera/projects/spark-core/src/main/resources/student.csv")

val studentPairRDD = studentRDD.map(rec => {
      val fieldArr = rec.split(",")
      (fieldArr(0),fieldArr(1),fieldArr(2).toDouble,fieldArr(3))
    })
 
val totalmarksRDD = studentPairRDD.reduceByKey(_+_). Can you help mne to fix this. Because I am not able to fix this.

Comment: Do you want a solution with RDD or will a solution with Dataframe also work?